Spearman correalation in R between different categories on likert scale data
i have a data set with 2 columns.One column is the answers in a likert ordinal Scale and the second column is the category of each question.
 df
# A tibble: 50 × 2
   answers           Cat  
   <fct>             <chr>
 1 Very Satisfied    A    
 2 Satisfied         A    
 3 Very Satisfied    B    
 4 Average           B    
 5 Dissatisfied      C    
 6 Average           A    
 7 Very Satisfied    A    
 8 Very Satisfied    B    
 9 Satisfied         B    
10 Very Dissatisfied C    

i want to calculate the Spearman Correlation matrix between each category  A,B and C. So the resulted matrix must be a 3 times 3 matrix with the main diagonal to be 1. Because the data are likert scaled i choose the Spearman correlation .
How can i do that in R ?
 structure(list(answers = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, NA, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, NA), levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), 
    Cat = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


You've got 20 answers for categories A and B but only 10 for category C.

@Edward i have edited it.I am sorry you are correct.

How are the rows ordered? Where is the question id?

Your answers are factors, not numeric, so you cannot compute the correlations, unless you convert them to numeric. You also didn't specify the question ID. Assuming that the ordering for each category matches the same question, you can use the following code:
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)

df2 <- mutate(df, answers=as.numeric(answers),
              qid=row_number(), .by=Cat) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=Cat, values_from=answers)

cor(df2[,-1], method = "spearman", use="pairwise.complete.obs")


          A         B         C
A 1.0000000 0.4439327 0.5145403
B 0.4439327 1.0000000 0.1429033
C 0.5145403 0.1429033 1.0000000


am i safe to convert likert scale data to numeric  in order to perform correlation? This is order scale data.The Spearman is rank correlation.Converting them to numbers will solve the problem ?

Unless you have some other way to convert these likert-type responses to numeric.
